# Failed to populate table in haml with database values - Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

I have a site where customers can purchase tickets for an event and created a `Reporter::EventTickets` class to generate a hash for the relevant information I need. `Reporter::EventTickets` is called in a Reports controller, and ultimately I want to view this on an admin report page.

I cannot get the information to display on my table in my haml view file! 
I've tried everything I can think and am at a complete loss for what to do.

Information is being saved to the database (PostgreSQL) successfully and the EventTickets class is transforming data properly (passing RSpec tests).

Code:

```
class Reporter::EventTickets
  include Virtus.model

  def events
    products.map do |product|
      line_items = LineItem.includes(:order)
        .where("orders.completed_at IS NOT NULL")
        .where(purchasable_type: "Product", purchasable_id: product.id)
        .references(:order)

      ticket_purchases = line_items.map do |line_item|
        order = line_item.order

        [order.bill_address_full_name, order.email, line_item.quantity]
      end
      total = ticket_purchases.reduce(0) { |sum, purchase| sum + purchase.last }

      {
        date: product.event_date,
        name: product.name,
        total: total,
        purchases: ticket_purchases.sort
      }
    end
  end

  private

  def products
    Ticket.where("event_date >= ?", week_ago_in_time_zone).order("event_date ASC")
  end

  def week_ago_in_time_zone
    (Time.current - 7.days).to_date
  end

end
```

Controller:

```
def event_tickets
    @reporter = Reporter::EventTickets.new
    @csv_link = admin_reports_event_tickets_path(format: :csv)
    respond_with @reporter
end
```

Models:

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :line_items, dependent: :destroy
```

```
class LineItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :order, touch: true
  belongs_to :purchasable, polymorphic: true
```

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Purchasable
  has_many :line_items, as: :purchasable
```

View:

```
= render partial: "admin/shared/header", locals: {title: "Event Ticket Purchases"}
.container-fluid.padded
  = render partial: "admin/shared/notifications"
  .row-fluid.hidden-print
    = link_to "Download CSV", @csv_link, class: "btn btn-blue"
  .row-fluid
    - @reporter.events.each do |event|
      %h3
        = event[:date].strftime("%_m/%e")
        = event[:name]
      .box
        %table.table.table-normal
          %thead
            %tr
              %td Name
              %td Email
              %td Tickets
          %tbody
            - event[:purchases].each do |purchase|
              %tr
                - purchase.each do |column|
                  %td= column
            %tr
              %td{:colspan => "2"}
                %b TOTAL
              %td
                %b= event[:total]
```

There are no errors from Rails and the page loads with the title and button. The table just does not populate.

Comment: Have you confirmed that `@reporter.events` is returning a non-empty `array`?

Comment: Just checked and `@reporter.events` is returning an empty array. Any idea why it is passing RSpec test for pulling info but working correctly for real data? I know it's got to be something simple I missed...

Comment: Are you sure you have `Ticket`s that meet the specified criteria? The answer to your RSpec question is that you've probably configured your test data to return values for `Ticket` but your live data is probably not returning values for `Ticket`. Or, at least that's my guess.

Comment: That was it - I had test date that was outside of my specifications - changed the `week_ago_in_time_zone` to allow all dates from today back a full year and the table populated. Thanks @jvillian!

Comment: Added as an answer for future searchers. Please upvote/accept as you please.

Answer (score 0):

As debugged in comments, your code is fine. With live data, this:

```
Ticket.where("event_date >= ?", week_ago_in_time_zone).order("event_date ASC")
```

...however, is returning an empty result set. So this:

```
products.map do |product|
  ...
end
```

...is returning an empty array.

Your RSpec test passed because you had `Ticket` records in your test data that met the criteria and, therefore, `products.map` was returning a non-empty array.